# How to include a project in a solution but have it unloaded by default?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions, solution, suo

Is this possible to configure in the SLN file, or just in the SUO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Solution Load Manager](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/66350dbe-ed01-4120-bea2-5564eff7b0b2) extension to set default load policy for projects in a solution (demand load, background load, load if needed, and explicit load only), as well as set the load priority for projects in a solution.

Comment: I checked it out and it doesn't save nothing in the SLN file. But it is good anyway