# VS 2010: Where are solution settings stored?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, settings, solution

You know how you go to solution properties and are able to change the startup project?  You can choose current selection, single startup project, or multiple startup projects.  Where is this stored on disk?

I ask because we use SourceGear Vault for our code repository where we have three separate branches for our code: dev, staging, and production.  Because we do mid-month staging deployments so the client can see various items in the release as they are completed, we are constantly deleting and rebranching branches.  This results in us losing these settings every time.  It's more of a nuisance than anything.  What I would like to do is tell the solution to point to a file outside of the folder so that the solution settings will always be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link answers my question:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/321663/allow-location-change-for-ncb-user-aps-suo-files

Looks like they won't be address this any time soon.  Not a show stopper, but it'd be nice to relocate the .suo file.

Answer (score 2):

It is stored in the [suo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165909.aspx) file in binary format. This file is usually placed in the same folder as your [sln](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhkhh4zs.aspx) file.

Since its a binary I am not sure if you will be able to do anything with it directly. So [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781732/how-to-include-a-project-in-a-solution-but-have-it-unloaded-by-default/4786024#4786024) might be related.